# Nokogiri XSLT tagging document as XML type when using JSON

Tags: ruby, xml, json, xslt, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to transform an XML document to JSON. The code is straight forward:

```
@document = Nokogiri::XML(entry.data)
xslt = Nokogiri::XSLT(File.read("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../../xslt/my.xslt"))
transform = xslt.transform(@document)
```

`entry` in this case is a Mongoid based model and data is an XML blob attribute stored as a string on MongoDB.

When I dump the contents of `transform`, the JSON is there. The problem is, Nokogiri is tagging the top of the document with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

What's the correct way of addressing that?

Comment: what is `@document` ?

Comment: good point - updated my question to clarify where @document came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `#apply_to` method as below([**`Source`**](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/247)):

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc  = Nokogiri::XML('<?xml version="1.0"><root />')
xslt = Nokogiri::XSLT("<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'/>")
puts xslt.transform(doc)
puts "######"
puts xslt.apply_to(doc)

# >> <?xml version="1.0"?>
# >> ######
# >>
```

Comment: Using apply_to instead of transform did the trick. Guess I have some reading to do - and thank you for the solution.